# Defining an Ordered instance for an Inner class independently from Outer class instance

Tags: scala, inner-classes, traits

I'm trying to specify that all AbstractTaskKey are ordered regardless of which AbstractTaskKeys container they belong to.

As shown in the code below, it's easy to specify an ordering for each specific outer class, but that means that in every different place I want to sort allKeys I need to use sortBy (or define an implicit ord that's specialised to whichever sub-outer class that's in scope).

I'd like to be able to define an Ordered instance for AbstractTaskKey that works for all subclasses of AbstractTaskKeys.

I've tried adding various variance annotations, subclasses and wildcards in a bunch of different places as suggested by other SO posts but to no avail.

How do I make my AbstractTaskKey's Ordered instance (or Ordering) generic?

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val someTaskKeyConsumer = new SomeTaskKeyConsumer[FooTaskKeys](FooTaskKeys)
    println(someTaskKeyConsumer.sortedKeysLength)
  }
}

trait AbstractTaskKeys {
  // Tried: traitAbstractTaskKey extends Ordered[...] too
  trait AbstractTaskKey {val id: Int}

  // Really I want _#AbstractTaskKey or (_ <: AbstractTaskKeys)#AbstractTaskKey
  implicit val ord: Ordering[AbstractTaskKey] = Ordering.by(_.id)
  val allKeys: List[AbstractTaskKey]
}

class SomeTaskKeyConsumer[TaskKeys <: AbstractTaskKeys](taskKeys: TaskKeys) {
  def sortedKeysLength: Int
    // No implicit Ordering defined for SomeTaskKeyConsumer.this.taskKeys.AbstractTaskKey
    //= taskKeys.allKeys.sorted.length     
    = taskKeys.allKeys.sortBy(_.id).length // works fine
}

trait FooTaskKeys extends AbstractTaskKeys
object FooTaskKeys extends FooTaskKeys {
  case object FooTask0 extends AbstractTaskKey {val id = 0}
  val allKeys = List(FooTask0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is putting your implicit `Ordering` in a companion object of `AbstractTaskKey` so that it's in a scope the compiler will search when it needs to fill in the implicit.

```
trait AbstractTaskKeys {
  trait AbstractTaskKey {val id: Int}
  object AbstractTaskKey {
    implicit val ord: Ordering[AbstractTaskKey] = Ordering.by(_.id)
  }
  val allKeys: List[AbstractTaskKey]
}

class SomeTaskKeyConsumer[TaskKeys <: AbstractTaskKeys](taskKeys: TaskKeys) {
  def sortedKeysLength: Int = taskKeys.allKeys.sorted.length
}
```

This won't allow you to compare instances of `AbstractTaskKey` from across different enclosing instances of `AbstractTaskKeys` but that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for.  If it is, you could define an `Ordering` with the path-dependent type of `AbstractTaskKeys#AbstractTaskKey`:

```
implicit val ord: Ordering[AbstractTaskKeys#AbstractTaskKey] = Ordering.by(_.id)
```